# Multiple users commiting changes from the same directory

Tags: git, github

At least two users are working **on the same directory** on Linux server. Each of us need to commit & push changes to repo, and those changes need to be properly indentified in Github.

How can I configure: `git config user.name` or `user.email` to enable more then one user to properly author his changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify author for each commit with --author option.

```
git commit --author="yourname <foo@example.com>"
```